# Double Oven Wiring

Tags: wiring, installation, oven

We are replacing the old double oven with a new one. The circuit in the wall has all copper wires, however, the wires in the oven are silver. Can you attach silver wires to copper wires?

Answer (score 1):

They are probably just tinned copper wires in which case it is safe to connect to a bare copper wire. However, you should check the specifications to ensure it is not aluminum wiring.  If it is then you need to use appropriately rated connectors to connect the two together.